# Where to insert Progressbar in WPF

Tags: wpf, progress-bar, tabcontrol, scrollviewer

My application has the following structure. I need to insert a Progress Bar at the end of the TabControl. How do I do? Can I add progressbar inside a SrollViewer? Any advise is greatly appreciated.

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <DockPanle>
            <Menu>
            <ScrollViewer>
                <TabControl />
            <ScrollViewer />
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _at the end of the TabControl_? Do you mean at the bottom of the `Window` or in `ScrollViewer`, below `TabControl`?

Comment: Yes that correct, after TabControl in the scrollViewer, or at the bottom of the window

Comment: This is not the same. If it is at the bottom of the `Window` it's always visible and `TabControl` will scroll and if below `TabControl`, in the `ScrollViewer`, then it can be hidden somewhere below if `TabControl` does not fit and goes over the `Window`

Comment: At the bottom of the Window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change this...

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanle>
        <Menu>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <TabControl />
        <ScrollViewer />
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

To this...

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel>
        <ProgressBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="25" IsIndeterminate="True"></ProgressBar>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="File"></MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <TabControl />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

You will get a progress bar on the bottom of the window, a menu at the top of the window.  The remaining space will be given to the scroll viewer per dock panel behaviour.

Comment: When I try this option, and have <TabControl Height="Auto"/> It does not resize to the window.

Comment: @user2495173, are you sure that setting the height to auto is necessary?  The tab control is a descendent of the dock panel and gets its size during the layout/size passes.

Answer (score 1):

For current layout you don't need both `Grid` and `DockPanel` you can do it with either one

**`Grid` example**

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Menu/>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
            <TabControl />
        </ScrollViewer>
        <ProgressBar Grid.Row="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**`DockPanel` example**

```
<Window ...>
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        <ProgressBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <TabControl />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```